# Two violin plots (horizontal and vertical) intersecting at a point

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I am unsure whether this functionality is possible through Plotly or if it is achievable with other plotting packages so I am open to different solutions.

I am trying to plot two violin plots in a single figure where one violin is oriented horizontally while the other is vertical. I would like to specify the point at which they intersect (*i.e* the primary axis of each). Ideally each would be transparent and interactive.

[Somewhat poor illustration of what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hqSu.png)

Thank you for any proposed solutions!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple Python libraries doing Violin Plots. **Plotly** is among them, check [its manual](https://plot.ly/python/violin-plot/).

Besides, **[Seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/)** is really good at this:

[image]

It is a Python visualization library based on [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/). The code snipped for the above example can be found in [Seaborn's gallery](http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_violinplots.html).